# Stash and List Pagination - custom links?

Tags: stash, pagination, orderby

In considering using a Stash list in order to get custom ordering of Previous/Next entries, I see that the docs provide only limited tags to use in the pagination function:

```
    {previous_page}
                <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Previous Page</a></li>
    {/previous_page}
```

Are the other list variables available here as well? Previous entry title? etc..

Comment: Are you talking about [pagination](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/pagination.html), or [prev/next entry linking](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/entry_linking.html)? By definition, pagination URLs cannot have entry titles or anything else, because each page contains more than a single entry.

Comment: [Pagination in stash lists](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Lists) has all of these options available as well as custom entry ordering, so I'm asking specifically about Stash. EE doesn't offer this with previous/next entry linking (but it would be great if it did!)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. FY the next/prev entry links do have undocumented `{prev_entry->title}` and `{next_entry->title}` variables.

Comment: Stash's pagination just loads the native EE pagination library so I think you're going to be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Croxton for this answer on Twitter:

> no prev/next row vars but would be easy to get w/ simple plugin or maybe mx_calc used to calculate get_list offset param.